# How to make KVO trigger after realm transaction is completed?

Tags: ios, realm, key-value-observing

I have the models which is `Group` and `Thread` which have relation like

> **Group** 1-Many **Thread**

I have this code, which will be trigger when leave group happens

```
[RLMRealm transactionWithBlock:^(RLMRealm *realm) {
    // Clear all unread in threads
    RLMResults<Thread *> *threads = [Thread allThreadsInGroupID:self._id];
    for (Thread *thread in threads) {
        [thread clearLocalUnreads]; // <-- Trigger KVO for thread
    }

    // Delete group
    [realm deleteObject:self];
} error:nil];
```

In the `ViewController`, I use `KVO` to observe some property of `Thread` and call this method when something changed

```
- (void)threadsControllerDidReloadData:(ThreadsController *)controller {

    // To prevent realm notification infinite loop in WorkspaceKPIDatasource
    if ([self.tableView.dataSource isKindOfClass:[WorkspaceTableViewController class]]) {
        WorkspaceTableViewController *workspaceTVC = (WorkspaceTableViewController *)self.tableView.dataSource;
        if ([workspaceTVC.contentDatasource isKindOfClass:[WorkspaceThreadsDatasource class]]) {
            [self.tableView reloadData];

            // Fix crash when reloadData is try to access group during leave since calling reloadData, the update
            // will not happen immediately. This line will force the layout to update immediately result in calling
            // - cellForRowAtIndexPath in the same run loop to prevent accessing invalidate group
            [self.tableView.superview layoutIfNeeded]; // <-- This solve crash
        }
        [workspaceTVC refreshHeader];
    }
}
```

There are two problems here

1. KVO is trigger without realm transaction complete
2. `cellForRowAtIndexPath` after calling `reloadData` will not run immediately result in even though the `KVO` trigger before group removed, when the cells are layout it crash why trying to access invalidate group.

I overcome this problem by choosing option 2 for now since it is easiest.
But I think the more reasonable way to do is let `KVO` trigger only after transaction is completed. In that case no matter what happen in the transaction will be grouped at the end.

Because of this problem which lead me to think that `KVO` for realm maybe will likely to cause some problem like if transaction is failed midway but somehow `KVO` is already trigger because of the change at object level.

But by reading the document [here](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#key-value-observation). It seems to me like the `KVO` will call when write transaction occur but I don't know why in my case when `Thread` is updated and `- threadsControllerDidReloadData:` is called why `[group isInvalidated]` still return `NO` in that method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the sound of it, KVO might not be appropriate for what you're trying to accomplish.

If you're interacting with data in a table view, it might be more appropriate to use [Realm's fine-grained notifications](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#collection-notifications) to register for changes. That system is designed to work with table views and will defer and deliver notifications at a time more appropriate for updating table view content.

Comment: I use KVO because the structure of our app is like 1 group will definitely have 1 thread attach to it. This KVO is observe for that particular thread. By the way, how can we observe one object without KVO? Do we need to make `[RLMRealm objectsWithPrimaryKey:] addNoti....` it seem overkill to me. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh okay then! Yeah, there's a proposal for being able to add a notification block to a single Realm object: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3431 It's definitely being considered!